# How to compute p-values from modified z-scores (Iglewicz & Hoaglin) for FDR correction?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, z-score, z-test, false-discovery-rate

I have made good experience with using the modified Z-score for outlier detection in approximately normally distributed data, which was also discussed e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339932/iglewicz-and-hoaglin-outlier-test-with-modified-z-scores-what-should-i-do-if-t) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123895/mad-formula-for-outlier-detection/274944#274944).

However, if applying many tests I suppose that FDR correction becomes necessary. 
My plan is to utilize the p values for that purpose, i.e., by applying Bonferroni or BH correction.
Now my question is, if the modified Z score can be applied for the calculation of p values just as for the standard Z scores, i.e., by utilizing the cumulative standard normal distribution function.

Comment: The answer is Yes, though I have forgotten the details which were implemented in a program written by Iglewicz for the stats package RS-1. RS-1 was a Bolt Beranek and Newman program that was eventually retired. In my opinion, it was a very good test for researchers.

Comment: It might help to post the definition of the modified $Z$ score.